# Fortran error: size of variable is too large

Tags: fortran, size

I have a long program and the goal is to solve the matrix system ax=b. When I run it, it reveals that "error: size of variable is too large".

```
program ddm

  integer :: i,j,k
  integer, parameter :: FN=1,FML=80,FMH=80
  integer, parameter :: NBE=1*80*80 !NBE=FN*FML*FMH

  double precision, dimension(1:3*NBE,1:3*NBE) :: AA
  double precision, dimension(1:3*NBE) :: BB
  double precision :: XX(3*NBE)
  double precision, dimension(1:NBE) :: DSL,DSH,DNN
  double precision, dimension(1:FML,1:FMH) :: DSL1,DSH1,DNN1

  ! Construct a block matrix
  AA(1:NBE,1:NBE) = SLSL
  AA(1:NBE,NBE+1:2*NBE) = SLSH
  AA(1:NBE,2*NBE+1:3*NBE) = SLNN

  AA(NBE+1:2*NBE,1:NBE) = SHSL
  AA(NBE+1:2*NBE,NBE+1:2*NBE) = SHSH
  AA(NBE+1:2*NBE,2*NBE+1:3*NBE) = SHNN

  AA(2*NBE+1:3*NBE,1:NBE) = NNSL
  AA(2*NBE+1:3*NBE,NBE+1:2*NBE) = NNSH
  AA(2*NBE+1:3*NBE,2*NBE+1:3*NBE) = NNNN

  ! Construct a block matrix for boundary condition
  BB(1:NBE) = SLBC
  BB(NBE+1:2*NBE) = SHBC
  BB(2*NBE+1:3*NBE) = NNBC

  call GE(AA,BB,XX,3*NBE)

  DSL = XX(1:NBE)
  DSH = XX(NBE+1:2*NBE)
  DNN = XX(2*NBE+1:3*NBE)

  DSL1 = reshape(DSL,(/FML,FMH/))
  DSH1 = reshape(DSH,(/FML,FMH/))
  DNN1 = reshape(DNN,(/FML,FMH/))

  open(unit=2, file='DNN2.txt', ACTION="write", STATUS="replace")
  do i=1,80
      write(2,'(*(F14.7))') real(DNN1(i,:))
  end do

end program ddm
```

Note: `GE(AA,BB,XX,3*NBE)` is the function for solving the matrix system. Below is the GE function.

```
subroutine GE(a,b,x,n)
!===========================================================
! Solutions to a system of linear equations A*x=b
! Method: Gauss elimination (with scaling and pivoting)
!-----------------------------------------------------------
! input ...
! a(n,n) - array of coefficients for matrix A
! b(n) - array of the right hand coefficients b
! n - number of equations (size of matrix A)
! output ...
! x(n) - solutions
! coments ...
! the original arrays a(n,n) and b(n) will be destroyed
! during the calculation
!===========================================================

implicit none
integer n
double precision a(n,n),b(n),x(n)
double precision s(n)
double precision c, pivot, store
integer i, j, k, l

! step 1: begin forward elimination
do k=1, n-1

! step 2: "scaling"
! s(i) will have the largest element from row i
do i=k,n ! loop over rows
s(i) = 0.0
do j=k,n ! loop over elements of row i
s(i) = max(s(i),abs(a(i,j)))
end do
end do

! step 3: "pivoting 1"
! find a row with the largest pivoting element
pivot = abs(a(k,k)/s(k))
l = k
do j=k+1,n
if(abs(a(j,k)/s(j)) > pivot) then
pivot = abs(a(j,k)/s(j))
l = j
end if
end do
! Check if the system has a sigular matrix
if(pivot == 0.0) then
write(*,*) "The matrix is singular"
return
end if

! step 4: "pivoting 2" interchange rows k and l (if needed)
if (l /= k) then
do j=k,n
store = a(k,j)
a(k,j) = a(l,j)
a(l,j) = store
end do
store = b(k)
b(k) = b(l)
b(l) = store
end if

! step 5: the elimination (after scaling and pivoting)
do i=k+1,n
c=a(i,k)/a(k,k)
a(i,k) = 0.0
b(i)=b(i)- c*b(k)
do j=k+1,n
a(i,j) = a(i,j)-c*a(k,j)
end do
end do
end do

! step 6: back substiturion
x(n) = b(n)/a(n,n)
do i=n-1,1,-1
c=0.0
do j=i+1,n
c= c + a(i,j)*x(j)
end do
x(i) = (b(i)- c)/a(i,i)
end do

end subroutine GE
```

Comment: When does it prints? Did you try to find out the line number? What is the exact error message? Can it be inside `GE`? (You would have to show it then.) It could be useful to use `iostat=` in your `write`s and other input/output statements.

Comment: Sir, I have posted the GE function. When FML=FMH=20 or 40, I can obtain the txt file, but when FML=FMH=80, it tells me that the size of variable 'aa' is too large@VladimirF

Comment: Please post more information, including what compiler and compile-time options, and the complete error output.

Comment: But in your code `FML` and `FMH` don't affect the size of `AA`, do they? Or do you in fact use the commented out version `NBE=FN*FML*FMH`? Post all relevant info including those things requested by Ross.

Comment: Do not change your question that drastically. That completely invalidated the existing answer! If you have a new question about some new code, ask it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your arrays (at least `AA`, `BB`, `XX`) into allocatable arrays and allocate them by yourself in the code. You are hitting the memory limit of statically allocated arrays. There is a limit of 2GB on some systems if I remember well (experts will confirm or give the right numbers).

Comment: Thanks,sir! So I need to revise the code as:                                          double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: AA
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: BB
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: XX

Comment: Yes, you got it. and do `allocate( AA(3*NBE,3*NBE), BB(3*NBE), XX(3*NBE) )` in the code before you start using those variables

Comment: If I use allocate( AA(3*NBE,3*NBE), BB(3*NBE), XX(3*NBE) ),  I do not need to re-define the variables?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean. Anyway when you declare it as allocatable, you need the allocate statement to request the memory space for those variables.

Comment: I thought the same, but notice that in the code in the question the size of the arrays is a constant number, not depending an any FML or FMH. But the OP is changing the code all the time, so that we really cannot trust him what the actaual code is. I asked about this issue in a comment yesterday, because I supposed this is the answer, but no response...

Comment: @VladimirF, the OP seems confused as you have seen, maybe less experience in programming. When I spot `(3*80*80)^2` for the size of the array `AA`, which is actually close to 3 GB for `8` byte `double precision`, I could not think of any other problem first.